# emacs -nw: how can I turn off the reverse video for directories in dired?

Tags: dired, faces, terminal-emacs, ansi-term, emacs-nox

How can I turn off the reverse video for directories in dired?

As you see
`emacs -Q -nw --color=never .` has still too much color:

[image: emacs -nw in dired]

The only thing I want to have with white background is my cursor.
Everything else should have a black background.
Otherwise the only way to tell where the cursor
is is looking for the blinking.

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.2.2
Copyright (C) 2017
```

Yes, I enjoy using old emacs versions over ssh to far away places.

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor on such a directory name and use `C-u C-x =`. That will tell you (at the bottom of buffer `*Help*`) what face is used there. In this case, it likely tells you that face `dired-directory` is used there:

```
  There are text properties here:
  dired-filename       t
  face                 dired-directory
  fontified            t
  help-echo            "mouse-2: visit this file in other window"
  mouse-face           highlight
```

Use `M-x customize-face dired-directory` to customize the face. If you change its definition to just inherit from face `default` then it won't look different from the non-directory files.

Comment: Thanks, but I chose simply a shell alias emacs="emacs -eval '(global-font-lock-mode 0)'"   to make it easier to prototype to potentially hundreds of systems, without needing interaction with the "customize" system.

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like all there is is:

```
  -D, --basic-display
      This  option  disables many display features; use it for
      debugging Emacs.
```

Well, at least it works!

(Regarding `--color=never`, that is in the X-windows part of the man page, so of course it won't help.)

Answer (score 0):

```
emacs -Q -nw -eval '(global-font-lock-mode 0)' .
```

Also does the job, but disables fewer features. (Although I can't tell the difference.)

Comment: FWIW, neither of your answers answers your question as posed. What you asked was how to (only) *not have reverse video for directories in Dired*. That's quite specific. Instead, your answers *turn off all highlighting everywhere*. (How to get repair a crack in my sidewalk? Drop a bomb - that'll remove all sidewalks. ;-))

Comment: Your only was not my only. Anyway, I also welcome other solutions that will work on readonly filesystems. I.e., no .emacs* files allowed.